# How to make NavigationBar rotate with device

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have added a navigation bar programmatically to my app as follows:

```
    //Setup Navigationbar:
    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.width, 44)];

    UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Navigation Title"];
    //Navigationbar left items:


    UIButton *fileButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fileButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadFile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [fileButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuicon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    fileButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
    fileButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    newItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fileButton];
   navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigItem,nil];


    //NavigationBar appearance:
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



    [self.window addSubview: navBar];
    [self setTitle:@"Empty"];
```

Problem is i can't get it to rotate with the device, As you can see im adding the bar to the windows of my AppDelegate. How do i make it follow the rotation and autoresize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the rotation of the navbar it needs to be added to a view that reacts on the rotation of the device. I fixed the issue by switching from `[self.window addSubview: navBar];` to `[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: navBar];`